# SSH library support for windows

Tags: python, ssh, robotframework

I want to use ssh library 2.0 for robot in windows. Can you tell me the link from where I can download the same for windows? Or does it actually have support for windows?

Answer (score 1):

It has support for windows. There are specific installation instructions for windows. There is a dependency on PyCrypto which must be installed before using SSHLibrary.

See https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-sshlibrary/wiki/InstallationInstructions#Windows

Comment: I have PyCryto already installed on my machine.
Do i have to install a particular verison of PyCryto in order to use SSH library 2.0.2?

Comment: I do not know. I do know that if you follow the instructions linked to in the answer, it should work. My team has successfully used it. If it's not working for you, you should post a question with details about how you installed it, and the exact errors that you are getting.